# Spring Tool Suites freezes in backend with Win10, with Win7 it worked fine

Tags: spring, eclipse

I have this adjustments for my STS in STS.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-
1740
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

and it takes a few seconds sometimes especially while debugging. Actually I don't know what to do. Maybe someone has any hint improving this.

[image: Version]

[image: Plugins]

Comment: Were you using the same STS version with the same ini parameters on Windows 7?

Comment: What eclipse and spring versions are you using? Could you add it to the question?